# Ncurses scrollable text reader

Tags: ncurses

I need to implement a simple text reader, sort of like **less** for unix, using ncurses.

I'm having problems understanding how to do so. I currently have a window, and everytime I press the down key (for example) I refresh all the lines at the appropriate starting point, giving it a scrolling-like feel. The problem comes with text-wrapping, which unfortunately screws up my current system.

I was wondering if some of you already did something like this and could help me out. I frankly can't find anything related to this on Google other than "pad"s, which apparently aren't scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   int prefresh(WINDOW *pad, int pminrow, int pmincol,
         int sminrow, int smincol, int smaxrow, int smaxcol);
```

prefresh's 2nd and 3rd parameters are its positioning values. With a little math you can increase/decrease *pminrow* for a vertical scrolling effect.